# What is it called when a page scrolling does not push the main image, instead, moves over it?

Tags: html, css

I would like to do it to the first page ad then have the third page come over se second instead o pushing it.

Such as here:

http://mindrudan.com/

Also, how would I have the "coming over" page to do so with only one click of the mouse scrol wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your inspector and figure it out yourself next time.

`background-size: cover;`

For your second question:

Different solutions are possible. The easiest one would be linking to an element using an anchor.

```
<div id="first-page">
    <a id="scrollto" href="#second-page">Scroll down</a>
</div>
<div id="second-page">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

You'll probably want to smoothscroll to the second page. This can be done easily using JS (and jQuery). Example:

```
$('#scrollto')
.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //will prevent jumping to second page

    $('html, body') //unfortunately you'll have to use both selectors for compatibility
    .animate({
        'scrollTop', $('#second-page').offset().top + 'px' //gets Y-offset of element relative to page
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: the hostility (a question is a question, you don't know my level)

Comment: You're right. Still, better try not to ask questions which can be answered easily by Googling 'round a bit. I've expanded my answer with an answer to your second question which I didn't see initially.